# React-hook-form - registering field works properly but logging value is not working - issue with passing ref

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hook-form

I am using `semantic-ui-react` with `react-hook-form`, but I am struggling with passing a ref to `Form.Input`.

As you can see, I am using the `hookform/devtools` debugger, and I can see that the email and password fields are registered

[image].

I can also log whether the field is touched or not, but I can't see the entered value.

I am trying to pass register from login page to `Form.Input`

What am I doing wrong?

**data.ts**

```js
import { ElementProps } from "../../components/Widgets/types";

export const fields: ElementProps[] = [
  {
    inputType: "text",
    fieldName: "email",
    inputLabel: "Email",
    inputPlaceholder: "Email",
    icon: "at",
    config: {
      required: "This field is required.",
      validate: (value) => {
        const emailRegex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}$/;
        return emailRegex.test(value) || "Invalid email format.";
      },
    },
  },
  {
    inputType: "password",
    fieldName: "password",
    inputLabel: "Password",
    inputPlaceholder: "Password",
    icon: "lock",
    config: {
      required: "This field is required.",
    },
  },
];
```

**Login form** (register passed as prop)

```js
import { FieldValues, SubmitHandler, useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import { ApplicationForm, Grid, SocialAuth } from "../../components";
import { fields } from "./data";
import style from "./login.module.css";

import { DevTool } from "@hookform/devtools";

const LoginForm = () => {
  const { register, handleSubmit, control } = useForm<FieldValues>();
  const onSubmit: SubmitHandler<FieldValues> = (data) => {
    console.log("Login data", data);
  };

  return (
    <Grid centered columns={1} className={style.wrapper}>
      <SocialAuth />
      <ApplicationForm
        form="login"
        onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}
        data={fields}
        register={register} <----------------- register
      />
      <DevTool control={control} />
    </Grid>
  );
};

export default LoginForm;
```

**Application form wrapper**

```js
import { useMemo } from "react";
import { Button, Form, Icon, Message, Wrapper } from "../..";
import { useApplicationFormElements } from "../../../hooks";
import { ApplicationFormProps } from "../types";
import FormElement from "./FormElement";

const ApplicationForm = ({
  form,
  onSubmit,
  register,
  data,
}: ApplicationFormProps) => {
  const elements = useApplicationFormElements(data, register); <----------------- register

  return (
    <Wrapper>
      <Form onSubmit={onSubmit} className="attached segment">
        {elements}
        <Button type="submit">{button}</Button>
      </Form>
    </Wrapper>
  );
};

export default ApplicationForm;
```

**Custom hook**

```js
import { FieldValues, UseFormRegister } from "react-hook-form";
import { FormInput } from "../components";
import { ElementProps } from "../components/Widgets/types";

export const useApplicationFormElements = (
  data: ElementProps[],
  register: UseFormRegister<FieldValues>
) =>
  data.map((element) => (
    <FormInput key={element.fieldName} element={element} register={register} /> <----------------- register
  ));
```

**Input**

```js
import { UseFormRegister } from "react-hook-form";
import { Input } from "../..";
import { ElementProps, FormElementRegisterProps } from "../types";

const FormInput = ({ element, register }: FormElementRegisterProps) => (
  <Input
    register={register}
    id={element.inputLabel}
    key={element.fieldName}
    name={element.fieldName}
    type={element.inputType}
    label={element.inputLabel}
    placeholder={element.inputPlaceholder}
    icon={element.icon}
    error={{
      content: element.config?.required,
      pointing: "after",
    }}
  />
);

export default FormInput;
```

**Form input**

```js
import { forwardRef } from "react";
import { Form, FormInputProps } from "semantic-ui-react";

interface CustomFormInputProps extends FormInputProps {
  register: any;
}

const FormInput = forwardRef<FormInputProps, CustomFormInputProps>(
  (
    {
      id,
      name,
      label,
      type,
      disabled,
      icon,
      error,
      placeholder,
      register,
    }: CustomFormInputProps,
    ref
  ) => {
    // console.log("register", register(name)); <----------- Here I see all props except value , why ?
    console.log("ref", ref);      <---------- ref is null here, why ?

    return (
      <Form.Input
        id={id}
        label={label}
        name={name}
        type={type}
        placeholder={placeholder}
        disabled={disabled}
        icon={icon}
        error={error}
        iconPosition="left"
        ref={ref}
        {...register(name)}
      />
    );
  }
);

export default FormInput;
```